# SVD of a block partitioned matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Given a block partitioned matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$

$$
\boldsymbol{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{A}_{1,1}   &   \boldsymbol{A}_{1,2}  &  \cdots  \\
\boldsymbol{A}_{2,1}   &   \boldsymbol{A}_{2,2}  &  \cdots  \\
\vdots  &  \vdots
\end{bmatrix},
$$

what can be said about its SVD decomposition in terms of its constituting blocks $\boldsymbol{A}_{i,j}$?

Comment: One thing you could use is the interlacing property of singular values. That is, if $[A\, x]$ has singular values $s_1,s_2,\dots$ and $A$ has singular values $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$, then we have
$$
s_1 \geq a_1 \geq s_2 \geq s_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_n \geq s_{n+1}
$$